# Get attribute code from attribute value

Tags: filter, code

Suppose **color** and **price** and **manufacturer** are three attribute codes.

**black** and **blue** are attribute values for color. 
**$0-100** and **&101-200** are attribute values for price. 
**hp** and **dell** are attribute values for price.

On category page, in filter section if I'm selecting attribute values black and &101-200. How can I get corresponding attribute codes?

In filter.phtml file sing this code I'm getting selected attribute code but not the attribute value in a proper format.

```
    <?php
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
      $items[] = $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar();

} 
foreach ($items as $item) {
     echo ($item."<br>");
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();

foreach ($appliedFilters as $item):

   $filter = $item->getFilter();
   $items[] = array(
     'code'    => $filter->getRequestVar(),
     'label'   => $item->getName(),
     'value'   => $item->getLabel()
   );

endforeach;
```

Comment: it's giving me the selected attribute codes. Though I'm not getting the selected attribute values.  after `endforeach;` I've added my code `foreach ($items as $items):
echo ($items['code']."<br>"); 
echo ($items['label'."<br>"]); 
echo ($items['value'."<br>"]); 
endforeach; `. How I will get selected attribute value at the same time?

Comment: Apologies, the second and third lines should get the `item` object, I have amended my response

Comment: I've added  `'attval'   => $item->getValue()` to the items array and printed it's value in my foreach loop  `echo ($items['attval']."<br>"); ` to print the attribute value(not label). Actually I've to pass these selected attributes in URL to search for products. I'm customizing default search functionality and first selecting n number of attributes and using a search button passing these parameters in search URL.

Comment: ^^ using `echo ($items['attval']."<br>");` I'm getting the attribute values for all attributes but for price attribute it's output is "Array" instead of something like "100-200".

Comment: You can just do : `if(is_array($items['attval'])) echo implode('-', $items['attval']); else echo $items['attval'];`